# Визуальное редактирование кода android

Tags: android, android-studio

Как визуально изменить уже готовый код в приложении?? Что я имею в виду, есть например приложение на андроид и для его создания было написано море кода, и вот теперь после того как вы протестили прогу вам необходимо написать документацию по приложению для заказчика например. Но если вы скопируете код из студии то будет заметно что временами слишком много пробелов или еще какой-нибудь чепухи, так вот чем можно сделать код красивым визуально. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил вопрос если что спрашивайте уточню что смогу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажмите

> Ctrl+Alt+L

Возвможно в вашей IDE в настройках стоит другие клавиши. Но по умолчанию то что я написал. Эта функция называется "форматирование кода"

Так же на Маке:

> Option + Command + L

Comment: а сторонних сервисов нету? или это достаточно рабочий вариант?

Comment: Ну убрать лишнее, и добавить нужные пробелы это поможет. 
Если вы или программист который писал код не соблюдал правила написания кода. То это обычно помогает сделать код красивее. Сам часто пользуюсь когда при быстром наборе лень делать отступы между операторами и.т.д.